# Dismiss Android Wear notification after action and no small icon

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

Two questions:

- How can I dismiss notification after user pressed action button
- Small icon is not display always the green Android logo

My code:

```
int notificationId = 001;

// Reply action
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:///?q=48.193479,11.569957&mode=w"));
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Create the action
     Notification.Action action =
new Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.map_white,
"Open Navigation", actionPendingIntent)
.build();


Notification notification =
new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.map_icon_notification)
    .setContentTitle("Navigation Notification")
    .setContentText("Please swipe left to start navigation.")
    .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender().addAction(action).setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.background_notification)))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();


NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
NotificationManagerCompat.from(ListenerService.this);

notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: In general, if you have two separate questions, it's better to post them separately on Stack Overflow. It helps other people find them more easily in the future :-)

Comment: @stkent I keep it in mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss notification

```
notificationManager.cancel(notificationId)
```

In Android Wear, Notification icon is display your APP icon

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  <--- change this
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it happen automatically? E.g. as via setAutoCancel() method on NotificationBuilder: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)